# Difference between legless, blue-eye blobs and legged green-eyed blobs

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

I just started this game and after leaving the first town I noticed there are two types of blobs roaming around.  The main differences are eye color and having legs.  Is there actually a difference between them other than cosmetic?  Does one of them indicate a harder battle?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legged ones have more (>2) enemies and types of enemies, like only they'll have Giant Bees.

Comment: Can you add what the other types do as well? The OP asks about all of them.